# Toggle Javascript returns error onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So I'm trying to make a menu open system on my site. But every time I click the div to activate the toggle I get this "toggle_visibility is not defined".
I've tried putting the script in the head and in the footer but still does not work. Suggestions?

Here's the site if you want to test it: [Link](http://chocobento.x10.mx/wp/)

This is the javascript I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
   </script>
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="user-image" href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('menu-options');">
<img src="http://chocobento.x10.mx/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/1-300x300.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="itslino" class="avatar avatar-180 wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-180 alignnone photo">
</div>
<div id="menu-options">
<a href="www.google.com">Test</a></br>
Test 2
</div>
```

Comment: Your script is commented out. Remove the comment tags

Comment: You didn't notice the syntax error it throws on line 1 of menu.js?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? He provided an explanation as well as the relevant codes. +1

Comment: Why would the comment effect the javascript? 
I have extra HTML in the script as well that I want to add to I had it commented so it wouldn't run. Let me try what you said. @RachelGallen

Comment: it throws error on line 1 in menu.js SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
<script type="text/javascript">?

Comment: @KaushikMaheta I was running the script separately and had the script thing on I just removed it. Still getting same errors though, including the one that says "toggle_visibility is not defined".

Comment: @コードバリノ I view your page source code and try to find toggle_visibility() function but it does not exist. please check .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove `<!--` from your script by either deleting that line or commenting it out as you did with `-->` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<!--
        function toggle_visibility(id) {
           var e = document.getElementById(id);
           if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
           else
              e.style.display = 'block';
        }
    //-->
</script>
```

---

If you're calling the script on a **JavaScript Page** (someFile.js):

Then remove these lines: `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` and leave it as:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: The above returns no errors and also makes the script executable again. Please explain the downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I removed it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Due to historical reasons, HTML comments are allowed inside script tags (when embedded in HTML) so the code in the question is actually valid. (The real problem is that the script tags exist at all -- if you visit the site you'll see that the file menu.js contains those HTML tags which is of course invalid.)

Comment: @コードバリノ So what's the problem now? It works fine when I try it.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem I voting for yours, I didn't know I couldn't right HTML inside a Javascript when it was outside. I never had issues in the past with this... but whatever. Everyone got downvoted so you deserve at least that thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your script is already in *js* file, so you not have to put your code in `<script></script>` tag. This tag is use when you write your *js* code directly in a html page. That say, your *menu.js* file shall content:

```
 function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
  e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

**NOTE**: browser developer web tool is useful to debug your code and generally you can use it by pressing f12 in your browser ( especially in firefox or chrome). See here an example for your site’s home page: [[IMG]http://i57.tinypic.com/dcvcyp.png[/IMG]]